# Robot_Pose_EKF filter TF fails

Tags: navigation, robot-pose-ekf, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running the Robot_Pose_EKF filter the transforms start to fail (the model in rviz flashes )
Originally  this was a long post that I solve before posting while the solution is self evident in hindsight it has taken a while to find.

I had to disable the TF transform that was published by my base controller  for it to work
reference this post

[link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/10511/frames-and-tf-with-robot_pose_ekf)

If someone could add this to the wiki it might save others some time

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29612/robot_pose_ekf-filter-tf-fails/) by [Peter Heim](https://answers.ros.org/users/71/peter-heim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 215 on 2012-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved by deleting TF published by base controller

---

Originally posted by [Peter Heim](https://answers.ros.org/users/71/peter-heim/) with karma: 215 on 2012-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-03-13**:
@Peter Heim, Can you mark this answer as accepted by checking the green checkmark at the left?